# Bad network sound quality

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

When tunneling sound to a remote pulseaudio server using the native tcp protocol, sound quality is pretty bad, it is particularly obvious on low frequencies where it sounds like badly encoded mp3.

The source is connected via ethernet to the router, the destination is a raspberry pi 3 on wifi with a good connection. The raspberry pi has a usb dac which plays local files normally.

My configuration is like so:

Source default.pa:

```
load-module module-tunnel-sink-new server=192.168.1.34
# also tried to add format=float32le rate=44100
```

Destination default.pa

```
# ...
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
.else
load-module module-detect tsched=0
.endif
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=192.168.1.0/24 auth-anonymous=1

# ...
```

Destination daemon.conf

```
allow-exit = no
avoid-resampling = true
high-priority = yes
cpu-limit = no
exit-idle-time = -1
default-fragments = 2
default-fragment-size-msec = 125
resample-method = speex-float-5
```